Bringing power to two bedrooms
I bought a new house and needed to build two extra bedrooms. The house is my residence. In both the new bedrooms, I have six outlets and a light. I have space to add breakers in the panel when I went to Home Depot to get the stuff I needed, the guy told me that I could run a 20 amp breaker on 14 gauge wire to a junction box and off that junction box I could run two separate 12 gauge wires to power both bedrooms. That didn’t sit right with me. I am double checking to see if that is accurate or not .

In short, there's a reason that that guy is working at Home Depot and not an electrical company. What he's saying isn't entirely wrong: the jumping off both bedroom outlets together and using 12AWG wire for it, but DO NOT put 14AWG wire on a 20amp breaker. And if you're adding these bedrooms, as in new construction, don't junction them. Put the homerun directly into an outlet box and jump between the rest of your outlets. However, if you plan to install lighting and outlets on one circuit, run it in 14Awg and use a 15amp breaker.

A 20A circuit requires 12 AWG or larger wire everywhere. A 15A circuit requires 14 AWG or larger wire everywhere. 12 AWG on 15A circuit is fine. 14 AWG on 20A is an absolute NO.
For lighting circuits, 15A is fine because modern lighting uses very little power. For circuits that include receptacles, 20A is a good idea but only required in certain locations (e.g., kitchens and bathrooms).
Note that 20A circuits can use 15A receptacles as long as there are at least two receptacles. A standard duplex receptacle counts as 2 receptacles.
In most areas new circuits for receptacles in bedrooms require AFCI protection, normally using an AFCI breaker.
There is generally no hard limit on the number of receptacles and lights on a single general purpose circuit. However, while more is better, there is a cost. The cost is both additional wire and breakers. Without a requirement for AFCI (jurisdiction dependent, but nearly universal now for most 120V non-GFCI-required circuits) the breaker cost was very low - typically under $10 for a 15A or 20A 120V circuit. But with that requirement, which applies to most new circuits, that breaker is often $50 or more. You can save quite a bit by using an AFCI/receptacle (similar to the extremely common GFCI/receptacles found in kitchens and bathrooms). However, in order for AFCI protection to work effectively, that receptacle needs to be installed after only metal conduit (which can itself contain arcs) and not at point of use. From a practical standpoint, to me that means put an AFCI/receptacle in a metal box connected via a nipple to the breaker panel and the rest of the circuit wired to the load screws of the receptacle. But that actually means AFCI/GFCI/receptacle because normally that panel will be in an unfinished basement or other area that requires GFCI.
All that being said, to me the ideal situation would be:

Lights for the two bedrooms on one 15A circuit. That prevents work on the receptacle circuits or a fault on the receptacle circuits from leaving you in the dark.
Receptacles on two separate 20A circuits. Either one per room or alternate circuits so that each room has some receptacles on each circuit.

